# Replace a string within a C char string (strreplace, no sprintf)

Tags: c, string, malloc, realloc, strncpy

Hello and sorry if this questions is already answered (in the way I want to :-) ) but I think I have a memory problem.
Assuming the following C function (yes, this one is very dirty and not optimized):

```
char *strreplace(char **str, char *dst, char *replace) {
    int replacestart = stringcompare(*str, dst), replaceend = strlen(dst), replacelen = strlen(replace);
    char *tmp1 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (replacestart + 1)), *tmp2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * ((strlen(*str) - replaceend) + 1));

    memset(tmp1, 0, sizeof(char) * (replacestart + 1));
    memset(tmp2, 0, sizeof(char) * ((strlen(*str) - replaceend) + 1));
    strncpy(tmp1, *str, replacestart);
    strncpy(tmp2, *str + replacestart + replaceend, (strlen(*str) - (replaceend + replacestart)));

    *str = realloc(*str, strlen(tmp1) + replacelen + strlen(tmp2));
    memset(*str, 0, strlen(tmp1) + replacelen + strlen(tmp2));

    strncpy(*str, tmp1, strlen(tmp1));
    strncpy(*str + strlen(tmp1), replace, replacelen);
    strncpy(*str + strlen(tmp1) + replacelen, tmp2, strlen(tmp2));
    return *str;
}
```

As seen, it should replace `*dst` with `*replace` whithin `**str`.
This works basically as expected. Here's the problem:

The output (`*str`) is not cleard out with zeros after memsetting it and has still the wrong length, even after reallocating.
Means, if the string is longer after replacing, the last chars are cutted of `*str`.
In turn, if the string is shorter, old chars are at the end of the char string are found.

What did I wrong. Mentioned that I don't want to use `sprintf` and no C++-STL, just want to do this with pointers in C.

Other words, what would be the right way to replace a string in an c char string with pointers.

Thanks alot.

**EDIT after reqeuest for more information**

I use this function as following:

```
...open a textfile via FILE type, determining file lengts (fseek)...

char *filecontent = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * filesize);
if(filesize != fread(filecontent, sizeof(char), filesize, fd)) {
    free(filecontent);
    return -1;
}

streplace(&filecontent, "[#TOBEREPLACED#]", "replaced");

...doing other stuff with filecontent...
```

**EDIT 2, adding `stringcompare()`**

```
int stringcompare(const char *string, const char *substr) {
    int i, j, firstOcc;
    i = 0, j = 0;

    while(string[i] != '\0') {
        while(string[i] != substr[0] && string[i] != '\0') {
            i++;
        }
        if(string[i] == '\0') {
            return -1;
        }

        firstOcc = i;

        while(string[i] == substr[j] && string[i] != '\0' && substr[j] != '\0') {
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        if(substr[j] == '\0') {
            return firstOcc;
        }
        if(string[i] == '\0') {
            return -1;
        }

        i = firstOcc + 1;
        j = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show how you pass parameters to `strreplace`? Also `stringcompare` is something you wrote? `calloc` sets the bits to `0` after allocation.

Comment: Debugger...............

Comment: Don't cast `malloc()` (and if you're casting `malloc()`, why not `realloc()` too?).

Comment: Multiplying by `sizeof (char)` is pointless. `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `free(*filecontent)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: `streplace` isn't defined.

Comment: @melpomene, about casting, yes I did this in a test of mine, pasted this one without cast.

Comment: Really? You're editing your code here instead of just copy/pasting a [mcve]?

Comment: "What did I do wrong?" You're trying to solve a problem using discouraged tactics: reinventing the wheel for no good reason (which results in wasted time), not reusing components that are likely optimised better than you could... not to mention, you're storing the return value of `strlen` into an `int`... Haven't you read the `strlen` manual? What does it return? Do you think introducing the overhead of a conversion is desirable?

Comment: You are all right, try to be better next time. But seriously, @Paul Ogilvie did within a few words, what I thought. Just looked at it, saw that is not the best and did "I would do it like this", as I mentioned in My last words of the OP. Anyway, thanks a lot for getting Me on the right way for the next time. Was a bit fast I think. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of the function is not simple as it seems at the first glance.

You should decide what action to execute 1) if the source string is empty and 2) if the destination string is empty.

For example if the destination string is empty then the standard function `strstr` will return the address of the first character of the source string. However logically if `dst` is an empty string then the source string should not be changed except the case when it is in turn an empty string. In this case the function should just create a new string equal to the string `replace`.

Take into account that as the strings `dst` and `replace` are not changed within the function they should be declared with the qualifier `const`.

```
char * strreplace( char **str, const char *dst, const char *replace );
```

Also the function should report whether a new memory allocation was successful within the function by returning a null pointer in case when the allocation failed.

Taking all this into account the function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * strreplace( char **str, const char *dst, const char *replace )
{
    char *result = *str;

    if ( *str[0] == '\0' )
    {
        if ( dst[0] == '\0' && replace[0] != '\0' )
        {
            char *result = malloc( strlen( replace ) + 1 );

            if ( result )
            {
                strcpy( result, replace );
                free( *str );
                *str = result;
            }
        }
    }
    else if ( dst[0] != '\0' )
    {
        char *pos = strstr( *str, dst );

        if ( pos != NULL )
        {
            size_t dst_n = strlen( dst );
            size_t replace_n = strlen( replace );

            result = ( char * )malloc( strlen( *str ) - dst_n + replace_n + 1 );

            if ( result )
            {
                size_t n = pos - *str;

                strncpy( result, *str, n );
                strcpy( result + n, replace );
                strcpy( result + n + replace_n, *str + n + dst_n );
            }

            free( *str );
            *str = result;
        }
    }


    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *hello = "Hello everybody here";
    char *str = malloc( sizeof( char ) );
    str[0] = '\0';

    if ( strreplace( &str, "", hello ) )
    {
        puts( str );
    }

    if ( strreplace( &str, "everybody", "Eurobertics" ) )
    {
        puts( str );
    }

    if ( strreplace( &str, "Hello", "Bye" ) )
    {
        puts( str );
    }

    if ( strreplace( &str, " here", "" ) )
    {
        puts( str );
    }

    if ( strreplace( &str, "Bye ", "" ) )
    {
        puts( str );
    }

    free( str );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello everybody here
Hello Eurobertics here
Bye Eurobertics here
Bye Eurobertics
Eurobertics
```

Comment: Thanks you for this detaild explanation. With yours and @Paul Ogilvie examples, I was able to solve My problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your function looks overly complex. Here is a simple, working version:

```
char *strreplace(char **str, char *dst, char *replace)  char *strreplace(char **str, char *dst, char *replace)
{
    char *start, *tmp;
    int n;
    if ((start=strstr(*str,dst))==0) return(0);
    n= (start-*str) + strlen(start+strlen(dst)) + strlen(replace) + 1;
    tmp=malloc(n);
    strncpy(tmp,*str,start-*str);
    strcpy(tmp+(start-*str),replace);
    strcat(tmp,start+strlen(dst));
    free(*str);
    *str= tmp;
    return(tmp);
}
```

With test function:

```
void reptest(void)
{
    char *src;
    char rep[]= "brave new world";
    src=malloc(strlen("Hello world of wonders")+1);
    strcpy(src,"Hello world of wonders");
    strreplace(&src,"world",rep);
    printf("%s\n", src);
    free(src);
}
```

Edit: my previous version forgot to copy the remainder. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, that is perfect and what I'm just looking for.

Comment: Fine. Hope it is not your homework I have been doing (in that case, I hope you learned :-)

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie  Why is not the part of the string after dst  copied?

Comment: Ai, @VladfromMoscow, I believe you found a bug..I'll be in the lab for a few minutes....

Comment: @PaulOgilvie actually not My homework, just played a bit around and got stuck.